# Review queue showing wrong review today number

Tags: bug, review

When going onto recent views on Safari Mobile I saw it says there were 5 reviews in the suggested edit queue.

Yet. In the users reviews today list there were only two:

[image]

Also for close votes:

[image: 2]

And low quality posts:

[image: 3]